# Can't start Selenium WebDriver: HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My first Selenium project.

installed Selenium Webdriver 3.141 using nuget in VS2019
Downloaded and executed Chrome WebDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
Get message that ChromeDriver was started successfully.

I've tried a number of different sample codes e.g.

```
[Test(Description = "Check SauceLabs Homepage for Login Link")]
public void Login_is_on_home_page()
{
    homeURL = "https://www.SauceLabs.com";
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/beta/login']")));
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/beta/login']"));
    Assert.AreEqual("Sign In", element.GetAttribute("text"));
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDownTest()
{
    driver.Close();
}

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    homeURL = "http://SauceLabs.com";
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

I've disabled both firewall and antivirus.

I get a new Chrome window with

```
data:,
```

in the address bar and `Chrome is being controlled by automated test software`

Then after a while the test crashes out with the error:

```
Test Name:  Login_is_on_home_page
Test FullName:  HelperTest.HelperTest.Chrome_Sample_test.Login_is_on_home_page
Test Source:    C:\src\repos\Helper\HelperTest\Class1.cs : line 25
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Test Name:  Login_is_on_home_page
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
   at HelperTest.Chrome_Sample_test.SetupTest() in C:\src\repos\Helper\HelperTest\Class1.cs:line 51
--WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
--TearDown
   at HelperTest.Chrome_Sample_test.TearDownTest() in C:\src\repos\Helper\HelperTest\Class1.cs:line 43
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56519/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have absolutely no idea what to try - can anyone help?

Comment: Switching to InternetExplorerDriver and I get one step further (sort of) - the browser actually loads the homeURL, but then I get the same timeout error

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to verify and experiment with that could help resolve the problem:

- Check driver compatibility. Upgrade the NuGet packages in the test projects and check the Chrome driver NuGet package matches the driver version on the agent (you can view this in the agent pool details).
- You can try to create the Chrome driver differently and specify a timeout for it, and increase the page load timeout.
- Also, see if there are cached DLLs and try running VS2019 as an administrator.